# Finding class of analytic function which are constant on cicrcles

Tags: complex-analysis

[image]
Suppose $f(z)=u(x,y)+iv(x,y)$

$u^2+v^2=c$

could anyone tell me how to solve this?

Comment: The Maximum Modulus Principle?

Comment: Is the constraint that $\lvert f\rvert$ is constant on _all_ circles $\lvert z-a\rvert^2 = a^2$ (with possibly different values on different circles of course), or are you to find, for all $a$ the holomorphic functions on $\mathbb{C}^\ast$ which have constant modulus on that one circle $\lvert z-a\rvert^2 = a^2$?

Comment: @DanielFischer Thanks for the clarification. I have uploaded the original question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I interpret the exercise as requiring that $\lvert f(z)\rvert \equiv c(a)$ on the circle $\lvert z-a\rvert^2 = a^2$ for all $a \in \mathbb{R}\setminus \{0\}$.

Since $0$ is an isolated singularity, there are three possibilities,

1. it is a removable singularity,
2. it is a pole,
3. it is an essential singularity.

Now, all the circles $\lvert z-a\rvert^2 = a^2$ pass through $0$, hence $0$ cannot be a pole of such a function, for otherwise $f$ would be unbounded on every such circle.

If $0$ is a removable singularity, then $c(a)$ must be independent of $a$, hence $\lvert f(z)\rvert$ is constant on a nonempty open set, and therefore $f$ is constant. Conversely, every constant function evidently satisfies the requirement.

So we are left with the more interesting case of an essential singularity at $0$. It is easier to analyse the situation if we move the essential singularity to $\infty$ by considering the function

$$g(z) = f\left(\tfrac{1}{z}\right).$$

Under the inversion $z \mapsto 1/z$, the circle $\lvert z-a\rvert^2 = a^2$ is mapped to the straight line $\operatorname{Re} z = \frac{1}{2a}$.

So the condition becomes that $\lvert g(z)\rvert \equiv c(a)$ for all straight lines $\operatorname{Re} z = \frac{1}{2a}$.

We know a family of non-constant entire functions satisfying that condition. It remains to see that there are no others (even allowing a singularity at $0$). [The maximum principle helps.]

Comment: The answer is given in the book is $f(z)=exp({A\over z}+B)$ with $A$ real constant.

Comment: Yes. And $f\equiv 0$, so $\tilde{B} \cdot \exp \frac{A}{z}$ would be better. $A = 0$ gives the constant solutions, $A\neq 0$ the non-constant ones. For $g$, that means $g(z) = \tilde{B}\cdot e^{Az}$ with real $A$. That is the family I referred to.

Answer (score 0):

Take $f(z) =\frac{2}{a}\cdot\left(z-\frac{a}{2}\right).$